# Unfortunately you can only import up to 3 files at the same time

Tags: carto

I'm importing datasets to CartoDB manually but the import queue seems to be stuck in 'Pending...'. I cannot delete these never ending imports as I can't see any button and when I try to upload more datasets it says:

```
Unfortunately you can only import up to 3 files at the same time
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: and as a comment which is not interesting for the answer of the question itself: it seems there's some temporal issues with imports at the moment. The team is working on it and it should be back to normal soon.

Comment: I've had the same problem when uploading CSV files. But when uploading XLS this problem disappeared. That may be a workaround for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working in the CartoDB SaaS:

The CartoDB accounts have a limit for maximum concurrent imports which in your case seems to be 3 -- which is the typical value for most accounts. Higher plans include more importing slots.

If you're working in your own CartoDB installation -- which doesn't seem to be the case:

Concurrent import limit is a property defined for each user, so the user would require to be edited if you want to surpass this limit.

Comment: The thing is that the datasets that are being imported seem to be stuck, as the loading bar is not going forward. I can't delete the imports and I can't add new ones because of the limit. But it seems that the import failed or something...

Comment: should be fixed now ;)